# Sending an array in url parameter

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I write AS to display exactly info that was typed on all textfields even displaying '@' on the url parameter.

[image]

I tested the form and the output looks like this -

email=cluneborg%40hotmail%2Ecom&lname=Luneborg&zip=75052&fname=Chistian

It should look like this - 
email=cluneborg@hotmail.com&lname=Luneborg&zip=75052&fname=Chistian

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../index.aspx");
var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);

scriptVars.fname = fname_txt.text;
scriptVars.lname = lname_txt.text;
scriptVars.email = email_txt.text;
scriptVars.zip = zip_txt.text;

scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);

function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void
{
    trace("Message sent.");
}

function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(scriptVars);
}

fname_txt.text = "";
lname_txt.text = "";
email_txt.text = "";
zip_txt.text = "";

}

mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, overFunction);
mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, outFunction);

function overFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace ('its working');
    mcView.gotoAndStop(2);
}
function outFunction(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace ('its working');
    mcView.gotoAndStop(1);
}

fname_txt.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox1);
function clearBox1(FocusEvent)
   {
    fname_txt.text="";
   }

lname_txt.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox2);
function clearBox2(FocusEvent)
   {
    lname_txt.text="";
   }

email_txt.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox3);
function clearBox3(FocusEvent)
   {
    email_txt.text="";
   }

zip_txt.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox4);
function clearBox4(FocusEvent)
   {
    zip_txt.text="";
   }
```

Dont worry about the ASP - that hasnt been built yet. I wanted to test the output first.

Comment: The output is correct, if you expect a @ to be displayed in a query then you should read about url and url query since you are lacking the basic knowledge of it.

Comment: What's the problem ? You can decode data using your server side script to get your @ !

Comment: decode in javascript?

Comment: not javascript, I told you your server side script, ASP in your case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didnt expect that kind of answer, but I was hoping somebody would come up with an idea to write AS3 to display the @ symbol on the URL parameter.

Comment: I put an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var str:String = 'email=your_email%40hotmail%2Ecom&lname=your_name&zip=111111&fname=your_fist_name'
trace(unescape(str))  
// gives : email=your_email@hotmail.com&lname=your_name&zip=111111&fname=your_fist_name
```

Comment: What if its a different email address by other users? So it cant be just hotmail.

Comment: No, it's just an example, I didn't like to put your email address. You can use it as you like, `unsescape` didn't know what string it contains ;)

Comment: This is probably a good example what Im looking for - http://test.adform.com/testpage/banner-specifications/general-specifications/transferring-variables-in-the-query-string/